# Get all the numbers between 0 and y just given the y

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So given a number (ex: 30), get ALL the numbers between it and 0 and print it on the screen

**In my case I can't use it with a for or while loops, because i'm already inside one and that's considered an unreachable loop**

I need to display these numbers inside an `<option></option>`

I know I can use a `range` with a single input, but I think it's clearer with `<option>`

```js
const TodoApp = () => {
     const items = [
        {
          id: "877635284991-9",
          name: "ex3",
          quantity: 12
        }
     ]

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: can you explain this `In my case I can't use it with a for or while loops, because i'm already inside one and that's considered an unreachable loop` better?

Comment: Anecdotally, I feel like hard-coding your options is not the way to go here.  You're using React; let React do the heavy-lifting.

Comment: What is the code snnipet you got a unreachable loop?

Comment: You can change your options with: `{new Array(n).map((_, i) => (<option>{i + 1}</option>))}`

Comment: How about a recursive function

Comment: const getOptions = (options, value, i = 1) => {
    let newOption = <option>{i}</option>:
    if (i != value) {
       return getOptions ([...options, newOption], value, i++)
     }
    else {
       return options:
     }
}

getOptions([], yourVal, 1):

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array and map the values to `<option>` elements.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const arrayOfSize = (size, fn) => Array.from(new Array(size), (_, i) => fn(i));

const items = [{
  id: '877635284991-9',
  name: 'ex3',
  quantity: 12
}];

const TodoApp = (props) => {
  const { items } = props;
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(items[0]);

  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        {
          arrayOfSize(selectedItem.quantity, i => (
            <option key={i + 1} value={i + 1}>{i + 1}</option>)
          )
        }
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp items={items} />, document.querySelector('#react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Here is a full example:

```js
const { Fragment, useState } = React;

const arrayOfSize = (size, fn) => Array.from(new Array(size), (_, i) => fn(i));

const items = [{
  id: '877635284991-9',
  name: 'ex3',
  quantity: 12
}, {
  id: '877635284991-0',
  name: 'ex4',
  quantity: 6
}];

const QuantitySelector = (props) => {
  const { value } = props;
  return (
    <select>
      {
        arrayOfSize(value, i => (
          <option key={i + 1} value={i + 1}>{i + 1}</option>)
        )
      }
    </select>
  );
};

const TodoItem = (props) => {
  const { name, quantity = 0 } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{name}</span>
      <QuantitySelector value={quantity} />
    </div>
  );
};

const TodoItems = (props) => {
  const { items } = props;
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {
        items.map(item => (
          <TodoItem {...item} />
        ))
      }
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const TodoApp = (props) => {
  const { items = [] } = props;

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <TodoItems items={items} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp items={items} />, document.querySelector('#react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create arrays of required size using `Array.from` ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)).

`Array.from({length:3})` will create `[undefined,undefined,undefined]`.

The 2nd optional argument of `Array.from` is a map callback, whose 2nd argument (index) can be used for your scenario.

Try something like:

```
Array.from({length: +items.quantity}, (element, index)=> {
    return index; // add option tag here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

How about a recursive function?

```
const getOptions = (options, value, i = 1) => {
    let newOption = <option>{i}</option>:
     if (i != value) {
         return getOptions ([...options, newOption], value, i++)
     }
     else {
       return options:
      }
}

getOptions([], yourVal, 1):
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const { useState, useEffect } = require('react');

const TodoApp = () => {
    const items = [
        {
            id: '877635284991-9',
            name: 'ex3',
            quantity: 12,
        },

        {
            id: '877635284991-0',
            name: 'ex4',
            quantity: 5,
        },
    ];

    function renderOptions(id, i) {
        console.log(i);
        var count = 1;
        const max = items[i]['quantity'];
        var ret = false;

        function exec() {
            if (ret) return;
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '<option>' + count + '</option>';
            count++;
            if (count > max) {
                return;
            } else {
                exec();
            }
        }
        if (ret) {
            console.log('Done ;)');
            return;
        }

        exec();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += `<select id="${items[i]['id']}"></select>`;
            renderOptions(items[i]['id'], i);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div id='container'></div>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Here's your solution

Comment: The question uses React.js library, where document.getElementById is generally not used inside components.